# How to add column to existing model in Doctrine 1

Tags: migration, database-schema, doctrine-1.2

How can I add new columns to existing table?

I can see that `Doctrine_Migration_Base` has a nice method `addColumn()` which I could use to add new column, but it only prepares the data required for the migration.

Usually this method is called from `Doctrine_Migration` class (via `execute()` from the command line). But Doctrine_Migration looks for the migration classes in the specified directory and then executes migrations one by one.

I need a way to call `addColumn()` without writing the migration classes to disk.

How can I do this (except direct calling SQL altering the table)?